# Converting timezone using dplyr syntax and attr function

Tags: r, dplyr, timezone, attr

I am trying to convert time zone using only dplyr syntax and the attr function, without loading other packages.

Reprex:

```
dt1 <- as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 08:00:00", tz = "GMT")
dt <- seq(dt1, length = 10, by = "1 day")
```

I could convert into the right timezone using attr:

```
attr(dt, "tzone")
[1] "GMT"

attr(dt, "tzone") <- "Australia/Sydney" # convert to intended tz
```

What I am interested in though how could I incorporate attr in  dplyr::mutate syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as a chain-able solution is concerned (I assume that's what you mean by "using dplyr syntax"), you could use `.POSIXct` as in

```
library(magrittr)
dt %>% .POSIXct(tz = "Australia/Sydney")
#[1] "2010-01-01 19:00:00 AEDT" "2010-01-02 19:00:00 AEDT"
#[3] "2010-01-03 19:00:00 AEDT" "2010-01-04 19:00:00 AEDT"
#[5] "2010-01-05 19:00:00 AEDT" "2010-01-06 19:00:00 AEDT"
#[7] "2010-01-07 19:00:00 AEDT" "2010-01-08 19:00:00 AEDT"
#[9] "2010-01-09 19:00:00 AEDT" "2010-01-10 19:00:00 AEDT"
```

Here is a minimal `dplyr::mutate` example

```
data.frame(dt = dt) %>%
    mutate(dt_Australia = .POSIXct(dt, tz = "Australia/Sydney"))
#                    dt        dt_Australia
#1  2010-01-01 08:00:00 2010-01-01 19:00:00
#2  2010-01-02 08:00:00 2010-01-02 19:00:00
#3  2010-01-03 08:00:00 2010-01-03 19:00:00
#4  2010-01-04 08:00:00 2010-01-04 19:00:00
#5  2010-01-05 08:00:00 2010-01-05 19:00:00
#6  2010-01-06 08:00:00 2010-01-06 19:00:00
#7  2010-01-07 08:00:00 2010-01-07 19:00:00
#8  2010-01-08 08:00:00 2010-01-08 19:00:00
#9  2010-01-09 08:00:00 2010-01-09 19:00:00
#10 2010-01-10 08:00:00 2010-01-10 19:00:00
```

Comment: I completely forgot abt as.POSIXct. Kept trying to access the tzone component in attr using mutate. This works perfect, thanks

Comment: @sactyr You're very welcome. It's `.POSIXct` though, not `as.POSIXct`. The former is a base-internal function, see `?.POSIXct`.